# Find derived objects in a container

Tags: c++, oop, vector

Let's say I have base class `Thing` and from that I have `Shoes`, `Pants`, `Shirt`. Then I have a `vector<Thing*> closet`.

How would I find how many `Shirt` do I have in my `closet`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) with a lambda that uses a [dynamic downcast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to determine if each element points to a `Shirt` (or a subtype thereof -- this would also catch, say, `TShirt` objects where `TShirt` is a class that inherits `Shirt`):

```
auto shirts = std::count_if(
    std::begin(closet),
    std::end(closet),
    [] (Thing const *thing) {
        return dynamic_cast<Shirt const *>(thing) != nullptr;
    }
);
```

Comment: Let's say I would want to find `Pants` that are `m_size` >= 40, how would I incorporate the function into the lambda?

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman Exactly the same way. `[] (Thing const *thing) { auto pants = dynamic_cast<Pants const *>(thing); return (pants != nullptr) && (pants->m_size >= 40); }`